# Show Sticky Post at the top but do not show again in the loop?

Tags: wp-query, loop, pre-get-posts, sticky-post

Regarding wordpress.org - sticky posts are displayed at the top but they also appear again in the loop.

For the main loop on my homepage I want to display the sticky posts at the top BUT I don't want the post to appear again in the loop, otherwise it appears redundant to the visitor.

Problem with the below code is they remove the sticky post from the top.
I want to KEEP the sticky posts at the top
but REMOVE/EXCLUDE it from the loop. Is this possible?

CODE A: This removes sticky post from top

```
function mango($query){
if ( $query->is_home() && $query->is_main_query() && !is_admin() ) {
    $query->set( 'ignore_sticky_posts', true );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'mango' );
```

CODE B: This removes sticky post from both the top AND loop

```
function mango($query){
if ( $query->is_home() && $query->is_main_query() && !is_admin() ) {
    $query->set( 'post__not_in', get_option( 'sticky_posts' ) );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'mango' );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sticky posts are prepended on the *first* paginated part of the home page, so try this:

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', function( $q ) 
{
    if ( $q->is_home() && $q->is_main_query() && $q->get( 'paged' ) > 1 )
        $q->set( 'post__not_in', get_option( 'sticky_posts' ) );

} );
```

to remove it from the other paginated parts of the home page.

Comment: It works!! You are a genius, I tell ya! Just one question. Does it matter where I paste this in the functions.php file ?

Comment: great - you should be able to put this anywhere in the   `functions.php` file (global scope) or better yet, create a plugin from this. @leko